# Property broker.crlFileList on IBM Integration Bus 10

Tags: ssl, ibm-integration-bus

I want to enable automatic loading of CRLs on IBM Integration Bus 10 broker.
But I don't understand, can I use only local files or IBM IIB can use HTTP or another protocol to donwload CRLs? And what is format of parameter's value in these command:

`mqsichangeproperties IBNODE -o BrokerRegistry -n crlFileList -v file_path`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's error in command on [article from IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bc49114_.htm): name of parameter is **brokerCRLFileList**, not *crlFileList*. 
Correct command is:

```
mqsichangeproperties IBNODE -o BrokerRegistry -n brokerCRLFileList -v file_path
```

Format of the value described in [article of IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bc49114_.htm)